# LINK_TEXT is capitalized but shows in lower case in browser's html code

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

On [this page](https://home.treasury.gov/policy-issues/financing-the-government/interest-rate-statistics), the LINK_TEXT 'DAILY TREASURY PAR YIELD CURVE RATES' is obviously upper case. However, it shows in lower case as 'Daily Treasury PAR Yield Curve Rates' in html generated after Ctrl-U in Chrome. It shows the same way in driver.page_source, where driver is selenium's webdriver, as well as after passing page_source through Beautiful Soup.

However, selenium is able to recognize the element only if the LINK_TEXT is all upper-case as it is in the browser.

What is going on?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] your question to show the code you have tried so far, with using the correct code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the CSS that applies to `h3` elements on the page is making it uppercase:

```
h3 {
text-transform: uppercase !important;
letter-spacing: 2px !important;
line-height: 1.18 !important;
font-weight: 700 !important;
margin-top: 20px !important;
font-size: 24px !important;
color: #0053a3 !important;
margin: 20px 0 !important; }
```

The WebDriver's **Get Element Text** command is going to grab the text *as it's rendered*, which will be affected by whatever CSS rules are acting on it.

Long story short, this is expected behavior in Selenium.

Reference: https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#get-element-text